# Refreshing collection (getResultList) of entities by entityManager.refresh

Tags: java, jpa

How to refresh getResultList collection of entities when JPA cache is enabled.
I mean:

List customers = query.getResultList();

????? > em.refresh ( customers  ) ! // i need refresh because the cache is enabled.

RGDS
Navid

Comment: Could you mention the provider you're using and how the cache is enabled (I guess this is a JPA 2.0 question but providing context information usually helps)? Actually, could you clarify the whole question, and format it appropriately (I don't even understand what you are trying to show)? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to "refresh" something?

Comment: I'm using eclipselink, glassfish v3, JPA 2.0 (I think, how to ensure the version of JPA)

Comment: I have two entities, like Customer and Orders, each customer has many orders, so i created @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationship between them, so when i find the customer entity by em.find() the orders doesnt make refresh and come from cache, but iam call em.refresh(customer) but seems this command doesnt refresh the orders of customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JPA 2.0 it might be easier to skip the L2 cache entirely, by using a query hint. For example :

```
Query query = em.createQuery(...); 
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", "BYPASS"); // skip the L2 cache.
List customers = query.getResultList();
```

This isn't available in JPA 1.0 though. If you're on JPA 1.0 you may have to use a vendor specific API. I believe Hibernate provides something similar to the JPA 2.0 hint (other providers might also have this mechanism). OpenJPA has a [refreshAll(Collection c)](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.2/apache-openjpa-1.2.2/docs/javadoc/index.html) method that should also work for you, and I suspect other providers have something similar. EclipseLink doesn't seem to have one though.

Comment: Not Work!
-> setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", "BYPASS");
i'm using JPA2 eclipselink and glassfish v3 with all default setting and coding

Comment: if i call em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); befor quering it works But I dont want to clear all L2 cache for this query.
how to turn your answer to work properly?

Comment: eclipselink doesnt have refreshAll !!

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to imply that all JPA providers have a refreshAll - just that your vendor might have something similar. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Since you're using EclipseLink you could try their hints instead of the property from the spec. 

Here are a couple of examples:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/cache_usaged#Used_as_NamedQuery_properties

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html

Answer (score 3):

Before you call em.refresh() you should clear the cache with em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();

This is a new feature in JPA2, so you must update your ORM framework probably.

Comment: if i clear the cache so there is no need to call refresh, isn't it?

Comment: my problem is how to refresh a collection of entities

Comment: the refresh overwrites recently changes from db to the object, so you have to call it for every entity object

Comment: if you clear the cache before you call getResultList() you don't need to use em.refresh()

Comment: Thanx,
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); works for me.